# Cannot add SSRS DNN module

Tags: reporting-services, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to test the DNN SSRS module (http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/sql-reporting-services-100-demo).

I downloaded the latest DNN 9.2 and stood up a fresh site, added the extension, and can see and add SQL Reporting Services module to a page. When I add it I get the following error.

```
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:c6b0ab82-4e48-4710-ab0f-8e8332d385d0

AssemblyVersion:9.2.0

PortalId:0

UserId:1

TabId:21

RawUrl:/Default.aspx

Referrer:

UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36

ExceptionHash:CXpfWR/wDEEz+CGsaTXbbcs2R5A=

Message:The type initializer for 'Ꭓ㐸뤵䵮줷퓣揠鉓' threw an exception.

StackTrace:

InnerMessage:The type initializer for 'Ꭓ㐸뤵䵮줷퓣揠鉓' threw an exception.

InnerStackTrace:

at Ꭓ㐸뤵䵮줷퓣揠鉓.챥岍ꟲᨿ쬬Ễ抪❱() at BS.Modules.SSRS.View.풑煁様팙ȕꔕ欤㴣(Object 뾗ꇽװ웇堇�힨퓴, EventArgs 쎭槛庱駃፴�煅暎) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
Source:

FileName:

FileLineNumber:0

FileColumnNumber:0

Method:

Server Name: JRUSSO-553
```

I tried adding the handler from the installation instructions http://modulemasters.com/portals/9/docs/ssrs/SSRSModuleHelp.htm?Installation.html but that didn't change anything.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is a commercial module. You should contact the author through the DNN store ticket system. Not much we can do here.

Comment: I tried that first, though I haven't received a response. I thought that there might be some configuration tweaks I could try. I think my next step is to try older versions of DNN

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the config of DNN but with the module. The author should make sure it works on DNN 9. Even if there was a fix you could not recompile the module library.

Comment: please not that DNN 9.2 removed a lot of deprecated api's.  As a result, projects using these older apis will not work.  Vendor's will have to build against 9.2 specifically to make sure it works.  Can you try installing it on a dnn 9.1 version.  that will let you know if this is the issue

Comment: I was able to add the module to a page using version 9.1!

Answer (score 0):

We just had the same error after upgrading from DNN 9.1.1 to 9.2

I contacted ModuleMasters and the solution is to download the latest release from their website, check the link on the right:

http://modulemasters.com/SQL-Reporting-Services-for-DotNetNuke